# Doors to uninsulated walk-in spaces

Tags: insulation, doors

I have two 32" doors in my house that lead to uninsulated storage rooms. I'm concerned about my utility bills, and I'm wondering if these doors are appropriately insulated. What kind of door should these be? And how can I tell what kind they are? Is it likely to be worthwhile to replace or otherwise insulate the doors?

Comment: Door type/construction can be identified visually. Please share photos. If you open the door and take a photo that shows the area around one hinge (capture an area maybe 18" high) we'll be able to see what sort of jamb you have as well as something about the construction of the door slab itself. Also, in what part of the house are these rooms located/connected (basement, garage, etc)?

Comment: The storage rooms are connected to the attic.

Answer (score 2):

To insulate a hollow door - I guess you could try to fill it with insulating material.  You might be able to drill holes in the attic side and fill it with expanding foam.  You might also just make a mess and wreck the door.  Depending how it's made and how patient you are, you might be able to fill it with cellulose insulation.

I have seen attic doors insulated by affixing insulation to the attic side of the door.  One place that was insulated a long time ago, they basically built a 3" deep box out of Masonite or hardy board and filled it with cellulose insulation.  Another I think they just glued a thick sheet of foam insulation to the door.

The old one, the attic door opened into the stairwell but there was enough room between the stairwell wall and the back of the door that the box of insulation didn't interfere with opening the door.  The newer one, if I remember right, the attic door opened into the 2nd floor hallway so interference was not an issue.

If you had an interference issue, you might be able to fix something that's not solid like a bat of fiberglass or rock wool, that would compress when you opened the door and hopefully spring back when you shut the door.

And of course in any case you can't go wrong weatherstripping the door to eliminate drafts.

Answer (score 0):

Interior doors are rarely insulated, it's the walls that are. Even exterior doors lack insulation unless they are the steel type. If you're worried about wasting heating and cooling, check around the door frames and threshold for any type of drafts. Do this from both sides of the doors. If you feel any or observe any cracks, get some weatherproofing strips from your home store and install it around the frames and thresholds.

Is there a way for you to insulate the uninsulated space?

Comment: The walls are insulated already

Comment: @StephenCollings  Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you said uninsulated storage areas.

Comment: I did. It's a door between an insulated space and an uninsulated space. The wall between is insulated. The door is not.